# Simulating samples from a population based on marginals

Tags: multiple-regression, sampling, population

In Germany's health care system, health care expenses $Y_i$ of individual $i$ in a given year are explained by $K$ dichotomous risk factors $(X_{1i},\dots, X_{Ki})' \in \{0,1\}^K$. The multiple linear regression model is:
$$
Y_i = \beta_1 X_{1i} + \dots + \beta_K X_{Ki}
$$
A federal institution estimates the $K$ parameters using data of **all 70 million individuals** with public health insurance. Money is distributed among 110 different health care funds based on these estimates.

The model is modified each year, e.g. by leaving out certain risk factors or adding new ones. The individual health care funds try to predict the financial effects for their respective fund by estimating the parameters for the Status Quo model and the modified model and then comparing the two.

Health care funds usually only have access to **their own data** and the distribution of risk factors among their insured may differ drastically from the distribution among all 70 million individuals. So for estimating the parameters they will simulate a data set. **They randomly sample from their own data until the marginal distributions of the simulated data fit the marginal distributions of the risk factors of all 70 million individuals.** They then use this simulated data to estimate the $K$ regression parameters and the financial effects.

Everybody in the industry seems to be doing this. I would appreciate any input on whether my main concerns with this practice, in particular that

- the marginals say nothing about the joint distribution of the risk
     factors,

because of this, two samples with the *same “fit”* between the
   simulated and actual marginals can and usually will yield completely 
   *different results*,

there are not even any objective criteria to
   decide what constitutes a good “fit” and

the estimates calculated from the simulated data don't have to and generally won't even remotely resemble the estimates calculated from the actual population data used by the federal instition

are valid and how to best convey them to
   people with no mathematical background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the simulation procedure, but (addressing your issue with the "simulate until the marginals look similar to country-wide marginals") you could do the following.

Consider a simpler model, with two factors $ A $ and $ B $, both $ \in \{0, 1\} $. Let's say that in the country, the marginal distribution of both are about 50/50.

Let's say that $ A $ is "smoked in the past" and $ B $ is "has lung cancer" (purely as an example, I'm not a doctor). Then, you'd expect that $ A $ is positively correlated with $ B $.

But if you simulate $ A $ and $ B $ marginally, without taking the correlation into account, and using the marginal distributions to do so, you'll lose the correlation and wind up with a smaller effect, i.e. you'll have just as many people who have $ A = 0, B = 1 $ as there are people where $ A = 1, B = 0 $.

Then, you might wind up concluding (if you run your regression on the simulated data) that there is in fact no correlation between smoking and lung cancer, and we cover very healthy people, and therefore we won't get allocated as much funds this year to cover healthcare payments.

Hopefully this is a helpful example that you could use to try and convince stakeholders that their process might be slightly fallacious. Of course, I'm kind of assuming a lot here with respect to the simulation procedure used.